# Jquery inefficient code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please point out the inefficiency in this code? I get high CPU usage when running this code on my html website http://dev1.envisionwebdesign.co/johnreid/campaign.html. Also the animation isn't smooth. I have placed this script in the   of my page. Is that also a reason why?

```
     <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#copy2").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav2").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'380px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy3").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav3").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy4").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-380px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav4").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy5").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav5").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy6").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav6").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy7").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'10px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav7").animate({'position':'absolute','margin-top':'450px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy8").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'10px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav8").animate({'position':'absolute','margin-top':'450px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy9").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav9").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy10").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav10").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy11").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav11").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy12").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav12").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy13").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav13").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy14").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav14").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy15").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-390px',opacity:1},1);
    $(".media-nav15").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);

    $("#copy16").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'10px',opacity:1},1);
    //$(".media-nav16").animate({'position':'absolute','top':'400px',opacity:1},1);



     $(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
 $("#copy2")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav2")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

     $("#copy3")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav3")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 
     $("#copy4")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav4")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy5")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav5")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy6")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav6")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

     $("#copy7")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav7")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','margin-top':'250px',opacity:1},1700);  

     $("#copy8")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav8")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','margin-top':'250px',opacity:1},1700);  


         $("#copy9")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav9")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 


         $("#copy10")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav10")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy11")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav11")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy12")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav12")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy13")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav13")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy14")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav14")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 

         $("#copy15")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'0px',opacity:1},1700);
     $(".media-nav15")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700); 


         $("#copy16")                             // get all <h2>s      // reset their background colours
  .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
    .animate({'position':'absolute','top':'250px',opacity:1},1700);

  }, 1);  // repeat every second


});   

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I scrolled about halfway through and then I heard a kitten cry out, from somewhere nearby.

Comment: jQuery animations are always a performance hook. The rendering engines of web browsers aren't designed to deal with DOM objects whichs styles change several times per second.

Comment: Aside from this being the ugliest wall of text I've ever seen, that site is pretty dope.  Nice job if you did it all.  Definitely need to optimize it tho lol

Comment: 1. You include jQuery three times!
2. Somewhere many many URIError's are thrown that apparently take up a lot CPU calculations to process.

Comment: Ever heard of variables? It will increase performance by storing things to memory.

Comment: I feel like this has to be a prank

Comment: Answer to the title: Yes.

Comment: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: onScreen" and counting.

Comment: @Pointy my developer disappeared to Africa so I simply repeated the the first line of code for each page. Any chance you can minify and sanitize it for me? I'll buy a shirt https://earlyevening.spreadshirt.com/. I like this one https://earlyevening.spreadshirt.com/men-s-heavyweight-t-shirt-A12626154/customize/color/4

Comment: This belongs on the codereview exchange

Comment: possible duplicate of [DRY javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821589/dry-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input guys. This worked for me. If there's anyway to improve this code, let me know.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        setInterval(function () {
            $('[id^="copy"]').each(function () {
                currentCopyID = $(this).attr('id');
                currentID = currentCopyID.substring(4, currentCopyID.length);

                if (!$(this).visible(true)) {
                    $(this).transition({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '-380px', opacity: 1 }, 1);
                    $(".media-nav" + currentID).transition({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '380px', opacity: 1 }, 1);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).filter(":onScreen").transition({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px', opacity: 1 }, 1700);
                    $(".media-nav" + currentID).filter(":onScreen").transition({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '250px', opacity: 1 }, 1700);
                }
            });
        }, 1150);

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
}, 1);  // repeat every second
```

The code above repeats every **millisecond**.

```
}, 1000);  // repeat every second
```

The code above repeats every **second**, not millisecond.

Also, there are quite a few animation effects happening, which may play into it as well.